# What Level of Video Card do I need to run 2 Dell Ultrasharp U2415 Monitors

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm going to be purchasing a new desktop computer soon, and I'm getting 2 [Dell Ultrasharp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NZTKOQI) monitors. These are 24" 1920x1280 monitors.

I'm going to be doing web development, and maybe watching 1080p video on one screen. I won't be using them for gaming. What kind of video card do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4K is basically 4x the pixels of 2K, and essentially what you have is 2x 2K monitors.As such except for gaming, any 4K capable video adaptor should be able to handle it. *Generally* You only really need a very capable video card for gaming. Even a humble onboard video adaptor on a bay trail can handle 4K video and should handle 2x HD screens fine.

Video ram is *less* important (except for gaming). Even with that, games scale reasonably well. For regular use, consider a few things.

1. Interfaces - most modern video cards can handle more than one output (for that matter, the *onboard* gpu on the bay trail processors found in intel tablets and low end NUCs can). However you want the right mix of outputs. If your monitors do DP, that should be your preferred connection, followed by HDMI (tho, at mere HD resolutions that should be a non issue - DP's really the only choice when doing 4K at 60hz, but HDMI has plenty of bandwidth for HD). DVI's fine but bulky and many modern displays may drop the physical interfaces for them.
2. Even a mid range card from the last few years should be able to handle 2x full HD (a nvidia 660 is supposed to be 4K capable), and even onboard intel processors can push that many pixels. For non gaming use, you might end up being able to use onboard graphics.

In the modern context, nearly any up to date GPU or iGPU should be handle what you want to .

If you're gaming, its a whole different ballgame, and you probably want to look up some benchmarks.  It'll also depend a lot on the settings you want.

I'd confidently go with nearly *any* modern video card or igpu with the outputs for my display here.

Answer (score 2):

An entry-level graphics card should do fine (unless you're doing extensive WebGL work). As long as it has 2 HDMI or DVI ports, you'll be OK for web development.

Comment: Will RAM matter at all, 8GB vs 12 or 16?

Comment: @AndyM Depends on your budget. Nowadays you should be going for 12-16 GB but it's totally fine if you get 8.

Comment: Thanks. One last question, is a 4th gen i5 going to be enough for the described usage?

Comment: Of course, it's fine. Really, you don't need a lot of system resources to do web development. Maybe a fast hard drive/SSD to bring up the browser very quickly, but that's about it.

Comment: @AndyM - You don't need a card with 8GB+ of VRAM to do what you want.

Comment: 8GB+ is a *lot* (Actually, somewhere between high end (6gb) and insane (12gb)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek New low end computers are actually coming with 8 GB nowadays. No joke - my school's new batch of low profile ThinkPads came with *8 GB* of memory!

Comment: I meant video ram. Maybe I misparsed it in context. 8gb is *minimal* in this day and age.

Answer (score 1):

i almost have the same setup 
and i use AMD Eyefinity3 with U2412M 1920x1200 off a radeon HD 7970

You can also make it a single surface
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMbHZ8Mn__g

You can find eyefinity cards for every price bracket.
I do recommend a midrange. not the lowest end. just because its nice to have a little 3d perf than none at all

Radeon R7 360 and R7 370 etc
(Important! pick the one with DisplayPort+HDMI+DVI)

Demo of eyefinity from Guru3D
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIqkYHePo-Q

and i almost forgot
AMD Kaveri based APUs support eyefinity as well (max 3 displays)